# I've created localization folders according to rules but it's still not localize

Tags: android, localization, imageview

As you can see I just create relevant folders for Hebrew localization pictures
The relevant picture has the same name in each folder but when I run my app the picture is not changed when I change my phone language.

[image]

What should I do?

```
The relevant code is:

<ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/backArrow"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_backarrow"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and create the folder like the examples in the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages#CreateDirs) like:

```
<resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country code>]
```

The directory will look something like this when using the `es_ES` locale:

```
MyProject/
res/
   values/
       strings.xml
   values-b+es/
       strings.xml
   mipmap/
       country_flag.png
   mipmap-b+es+ES/
       country_flag.png
```

---

### Edit:

I'm not sure if it's still relevant to you and my previous answer was the least bit helpful. But I've ran into a similiar problem recently and looked and asked around for a bit. This is [what solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292137/how-to-correctly-localize-android-resources-to-support-multiple-languages/52295160#52295160) for my situation.

If you've set the `resConfig` property in your `Gradle` file before without the language you are trying to support, those resources are getting removed and replaced by the default resources.

You can add multiple languages like this in your `Gradle` file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en", "fr", "es", "he" //Where you place the supported languages
    }
}
```